# Redux option doensn't seem when include from functions.php

Tags: php, wordpress, redux-framework

When I wrote redux framework option into header.php, it is shown.However when I add the same php code into a php file and include the php file from functions.php, it doesn't seem.

header.php:

```
<?php global $redux_demo; ?>
<?php echo wp_kses_post( $redux_demo['text-call-header'] );
?>
```

function.php :

```
include ( get_template_directory() . '/theme-color.php' );
```

theme-color.php contains same code above also global redux variable but it doesn't give any output.

why?

as a smiliar second question, also I can't get output from my custom plugin when I include theme-color.php from my custom plugin.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

to get output, you should load it on wp_head because redux framework doesn't work before wp_head.it is a timing issue.

you should wrap your function and fire it on wp_head.

```
function theme_color() {
    include ( get_template_directory() . '/theme-color.php' );
}
add_action('wp_head','theme_color');
```

so it will be loaded

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-ask).